# Many set theory and model theory questions.

Tags: set-theory, model-theory, large-cardinals

The questions:

1. Are there any cardinals $\kappa$ such that $\mathrm{V}\setminus\{\kappa\}\prec\mathrm{V}$? If so, I think a neat name for them would be "ghost cardinals", because their existance leaves no impact on $\mathrm{V}$ and it's properties.
2. Given a theory $\mathrm{T}$, what is the minimum cardinality of $\mathcal{M}$ such that $\mathcal{M}$ is nonempty and $\mathcal{M}\models\mathrm{T}$? If so, what is it respective to Peano Arithmetic, Z, ZF, ZFC, KM, etc.? (SOLVED)
3. Are there any cardinals $\kappa$ larger than the smallest correct cardinal such that $\forall\lambda<\kappa(\mathrm{V}_\lambda\prec\mathrm{V}\rightarrow\mathrm{V}_{\lambda}\prec\mathrm{V}_\kappa)$? (In other words, every rank of a correct cardinal is a substructure of the rank of $\kappa$, making $\mathrm{V}_\kappa$ very similar to $\mathrm{V}$, a good name for these is  hypercorrect)
4. Given a structure $\mathcal{M}$, are there any non-singleton chains of substructures of $\mathcal{M}$ ordered by $\prec$? What is the largest suprememum of these chains' order types when $\mathcal{M}=\mathrm{V}$? What about when $\mathcal{M}=L$?

Where I have gotten to so far on them:

1. If they do exist, they are not "definable" (i.e. there is no formula that is true for them and only them.) Every $\aleph_\alpha$ and $\beth_\alpha$ for finite $\alpha$ is not a ghost cardinal, and GCH implies every ghost cardinal is a limit cardinal.
2. For Peano Arithmetic, the answer is clearly $\aleph_0$. For all the others, there are no finite models of Z, ZF, ZFC, or KM, and since they are all $L(\omega,\omega)$-theories, there is a countable model (if any). Thus, for all of these, $\aleph_0$.
3. Every one of these cardinals are correct. Since not much is known on correct cardinals, this one seems hard to work on.
4. Yes, there is an $\mathcal{M}$ where this property is true. In fact, that $\mathcal{M}$ is $\mathrm{V}$. Clearly, the existance of a correct cardinal implies that this supremum is at least $3$ (as $\{\mathrm{V}_\kappa,\mathrm{V}\}$ is well-ordered by $\prec$). It is also true that the existence of a hypercorrect cardinal implies it is at least $4$ (as $\{\mathrm{V}_\lambda,\mathrm{V}_\kappa,\mathrm{V}\}$ is well-ordered by $\prec$)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- 1: No - since e.g. the ordinal $\kappa+1$ (remember, all cardinals are ordinals) will be a successor in $V$ but not in $V\setminus\{\kappa\}$. *EDIT: a better example, given any $a\in V$, is to think about $\{a\}$. In $V$, $\{a\}$ is nonempty, but $V\setminus\{a\}$ thinks $\{a\}$ is empty; in particular, $V\setminus \{a\}$ won't satisfy the [axiom of extensionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_extensionality), regardless of what $a$ is.* I think you're asking the wrong question here - a better question would be e.g. "Can we have an $M\prec V$ with $\kappa\not\in M$?"

  - Another question of this form, arguably more important, is : "Can we have an elementary embedding $j:V\rightarrow M$, for some inner model $M$, with $\kappa\not\in ran(j)$?" This is connected with [measurable (and larger) cardinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurable_cardinal#Definition).
- 2: [Lowenheim-Skolem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6wenheim%E2%80%93Skolem_theorem).
- For 3, the answer will depend on large cardinal assumptions - e.g. if $V$ happens to be a rank-minimal model of ZFC, then there are no $\lambda\in Ord$ with $V_\lambda\prec V$.
- For 4, you're trying way too hard: think about (say) an infinite pure set. Or the rationals, as a linear order. As to chains of elementary substructure in $V$, $L$, or similar, my answer re: 3 applies.

  ---

For what it's worth, I think it would be a good idea to get a solid grasp of basic model theory before diving in to the model theory of set theory specifically; in particular, I think that comfort with the basic tools like compactness, Lowenheim-Skolem, and omitting types is a necessity here (to be clear, I don't think omitting types itself is specifically necessary, but comfort with its proof and use is a turning point in understanding model theory). I think it's also a good idea in the future to not ask several questions at once.

Comment: Thanks! This was really helpful!

Comment: Also, I just realized Feferman's Theory is almost exactly the same is my question 4.

Comment: @Zetapology Regarding question 1, it may be useful to think about which other sets are automatically excluded from $M$ if we require $\kappa\notin M$. For instance, $M$ cannot have any ordinal of cardinality $\kappa$ or $\kappa^+$ or $\kappa^{++}$, etc., or their power sets or ... Noah suggested to look at measurable cardinals. Actually, the "right" cardinals to look at here are those coming from embeddings $j\!:N\to V$ with $N$ a proper class transitive model. See [here](https://doi.org/10.2307/2695094). (The relevance is that the transitive collapse of an $M\prec V$ is an $N$ as described.)

Comment: @Zetapology The other way to find an $M\prec V$ is if $M$ is a set rather than a proper class. Then of course many cardinals $\kappa$ won't be in $M$.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo To clarify, I didn't mean that measurables are the right thing to look at for the OP's question, merely that they (in my understanding) play a more fundamental role in modern set theory; and besides that fact, I thought they were worth mentioning since thinking about embeddings with $V$ the *domain* instead of the codomain is a counterintuitive thing to do initially. You're quite right that $j:N\rightarrow V$ is the right kind of thing for the OP to look at in the context of this question.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I understand. Definitely measurability is fundamental. Once one understands it, then it makes sense to venture into weakenings (presentations of weak compactness or indescribability in terms of embeddings, for example) and variants (like the "$\mathsf{ORD}$ is Ramsey" notion corresponding to embeddings $j\!:N\to V$), but not before.

Comment: This question was actually part of a DIFFERENT generalization than the one you all have made, which was:
Given a structure $\mathcal{M}$, are there any $n\in\mathrm{M}$ such that $\mathcal{M}\setminus\{n\}\prec\mathcal{M}$? This is clearly not true in $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$, but what about $\mathbb{R}$, and maybe other universes of set theory?

Comment: @Zetapology Ah. In most interesting cases, the answer is easily seen to be "no." For $\mathbb{R}$ (presumably with $+$ and $\times$): consider e.g. $n\over 2$. For a model of set theory, consider the set $\{n\}$. It's rare that you can remove a single object and get an elementary substructure.

Comment: Well of course in most "interesting" cases. You see, when I made theory that such structures exist, I tried to find one by making structures with so many elements that they were almost all completely similar. I have this sort of "Theory" that set theory eventually comes across cardinals that are similar to each other, or are particularly uninteresting. I'm trying to find ways to demonstrate this, but I'm becoming worried that it might be incorrect.

Comment: @Zetapology Well, like I said, **no model of ZFC** can have the property you're talking about. If $M\models$ZFC and $n\in M$, then $M\setminus\{n\}\not\preccurlyeq M$. So I'm not sure exactly what you're asking for. The variations Andres (and less relevantly, I) mentioned can occur, though.

Comment: I also just realized that Reinhardt cardinals basically create this idea of ghost cardinals, because they can be "switched" with other cardinals (via automorphism) and still have the properties of $\mathrm{V}$ stay relatively the same (via elementary embedding)

Comment: @Zetapology "they can be "switched" with other cardinals (via automorphism)" No, they can't - there's no nontrivial automorphism of $V$ at all. (Precisely: a well-founded model of ZF has no nontrivial automorphisms.) And regardless, there's a huge difference between "can be moved by an automorphism" and "can be omitted, while keeping every other element, without changing the theory of the structure." I think you need to think carefully about exactly what question you're trying to ask, and what the various terms you're saying mean precisely.

Comment: I'm saying assuming the existance of a Reinhardt cardinal which precisely assumes a nontrivial class automorphism of $\mathrm{V}$

Comment: @Zetapology **No, it doesn't**. Read the definition again. It gives a nontrivial **elementary embedding** from $V$ into itself; that's not the same thing at all.

Comment: Isn't that a type of automorphism?

Comment: @Zetapology No. An automorphism is bijective, while an elementary embedding need not be. Let me reiterate my previous point: before diving into this stuff, you should *really* familiarize yourself with the basic model theory involved.

Comment: Here's a good example of an elementary embedding which might clarify things: take the structure $\mathcal{Q}=(\mathbb{Q}, <)$ and consider the map $f$ defined as $f(q)=q-1$ if $q<\sqrt{2}$ and $f(q)=q+1$ if $q>\sqrt{2}$. Since $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational, $f$ is defined on all of $\mathbb{Q}$; and clearly $f$ is not an automorphism of $\mathcal{Q}$, since e.g. $1\not\in ran(f)$. But it's not hard to show that it **is** an elementary embedding of $\mathcal{Q}$ into itself.

Comment: NO NO NO I'm saying "an elementary embedding from V into itself" is a type of automorphism. "An automorphism is an isomorphism from a mathematical object to itself", and therefore an elementary embedding from V into itself is an automorphism.

Comment: @Zetapology I'm aware. That statement is false. I'll say it again: an automorphism is, by definition, bijective. Elementary embeddings need not be. An elementary embedding from $V$ to itself need not be an automorphism, and in fact (so long as $V$ is well-founded and the embedding is not just the identity) it never will be.

Comment: How so? I know both definitions, so what is wrong with this statement? Also, I do know what an elementary embedding is.

Comment: @Zetapology **Isomorphisms are bijective. Elementary embeddings need not be.** I don't know how many times I have to say this.

Comment: "Need not be" != "Are never"

Comment: @Zetapology Yes, but **in this case** they are never. For the third time: **there are no nontrivial automorphisms of any well-founded model of ZF**. So if $\eta: V\rightarrow V$ is any non-identity function (say, the elementary embedding corresponding to a Reinhardt cardinal), it's not an automorphism. I really don't know where you're getting the impression that it is.

Comment: Actually it's really easy to see directly that an elementary embedding corresponding to a Reinhardt isn't surjective. Say $j:V\rightarrow V$ is a nontrivial elementary embedding with critical point $\kappa$; this means $j(\kappa)>\kappa$, but $j(\alpha)=\alpha$ for all $\alpha<\kappa$. Now think about an arbitrary ordinal $\gamma$. By elementarity, if $\gamma\ge\kappa$ then $j(\gamma)\ge j(\kappa)$, and since $j(\kappa)>\kappa$ we know that $j(\gamma)>\kappa$; meanwhile, if $\gamma<\kappa$, then since $\kappa=crit(j)$ we have $j(\gamma)=\gamma<\kappa$. So $\kappa\not\in ran(j)$.

Comment: I got the impression from the definition of an automorphism. What does it mean for isomorphism in this case though? I might have the wrong definition.

Comment: I mean, considering we are talking about set theory, I assumed the simple definition of just any bijective morphism, but I guess it's possible that there are no isomorphisms from V to itself, depending on the definition of isomorphism.

Comment: @Zetapology "I assumed the simple definition of just any bijective morphism." Yes, that's what an isomorphism is. But as I've said repeatedly now, **there are no nontrivial isomorphisms from $V$ to itself**, and in particular a nontrivial elementary embedding from $V$ into itself **will never be** an automorphism (see my previous comment for a proof of this; it's simpler than proving the general rigidity of $V$).

Comment: There are lots of structures with no nontrivial automorphisms but lots of nontrivial self-elementary-embeddings; e.g. if $\alpha$ is an ordinal, the structure $(\alpha, <)$ has no nontrivial automorphisms, but if $\alpha$ is large enough it has *lots* of nontrivial self-elementary-embeddings.

Comment: So... what is a bijection on a class then? Do I have that definition wrong?

Comment: @Zetapology I think you understand bijections right. What I don't think you understand is that elementary embeddings do not need to be surjective, so there's no reason to believe that they are automorphisms. Why do you think that they are?

Comment: Let me ask this: do you understand that a nontrivial elementary embedding $j:V\rightarrow V$ will not be surjective (assuming $V$ is well-founded)? If so, *that's why it's not an automorphism of $V$* - automorphisms *are* surjective.

Comment: Not really... if so wouldn't there be multiple $j(\kappa)$ for some $\kappa$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65461/discussion-between-zetapology-and-noah-schweber).